# how to post to a route url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using this route :

```
Route::post('cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin','Panel\AdminController@checkUserPassLogin');
```

and my controller :

[image]

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use App\Quotation;
....
public function checkUserPassLogin(Request $request)
{
    echo 'test';
    return 'test';

}
```

and in the my view:

```
    function login()
    {
        console.log('test');
        var email = $('#email_admin').val();
        var pass  = $('#pass_admin').val();

        if(!email || !pass)
                return ;

        console.log(email+'-'+pass);
        $.post("{{ url('/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin') }}", {username:email,pass:pass}, function (data) {


            console.log(data);


            if(data == 'ok')
            {
                window.location.href = "..........";
            }else{

            }

        });
    }
```

`console.log(email+'-'+pass);` prints my values but `console.log(data);` doesn't return anything .

Comment: In your controller, remove the `echo` line and see if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work !!!!

Comment: If you're using Linux, how about using curl? Do a **POST** request like: `curl --data "email=test&pass=test" http://yourapp.domain/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin`. Did your `curl` print something?

Comment: Has your `AdminController` controller `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Panel;` ?

Comment: What does the ajax call say in your browser network tab?

Comment: on my browser network tab : status : `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: Set debug to true and use the stacktrace to see where the error is occuring. Error is on backend side, not in ajax.

Comment: @Ismail RBOUH yes.

Comment: Please check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undoubtedly, is a CSRF problem. In Laravel 5, all requests must pass through the Middleware which will not allow any POST requests without the correct CSRF token. To solve this problem:

Somewhere in your view add:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

Then in your ajax post data add :

```
'_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

It will look like this:

```
$.post("{{ url('/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin') }}", {username:email, pass:pass, '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}, function (data) {...});
```

One alternative, is to add the `csrf-token` directly to your javascript like you did with the URL:

```
$.post("{{ url('/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin') }}", {username:email, pass:pass, '_token': "{!! csrf_token() !!}"}, function (data) {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$.post("{{ url('/cp/admin/checkUserPassLogin') }}", {username:email,pass:pass}, function (data) {
```

To

```
$.post("your route here along with the base url", {username:email,pass:pass}, function (data) {
```

Example:

```
$.post("BASE_URL + "admin/checkUserPassLogin")
```

Where BASE_URL is set somewhere in your view, preferably a base view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var BASE_URL = '{{ asset('/') }}';
</script>
```